# Azure service bus: How many messages can be scheduled in a queue?

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I am trying to find what if there is a limit to number of messages that can be scheduled in a queue. I need to schedule millions of messages up from 7 to 21 days in future.  Looked at this but it does not say anything about scheduled messages.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-quotas#messaging-quotas

Comment: Any update now? Please feel free to let me know if it not work.

Answer (score 0):

> Service Bus queues support a maximum message size of 256 KB in the Standard tier and 1 MB in the Premium tier. **There's no limit on the number of messages held in a queue** but there's a cap on the total size of the messages held by a queue. This queue size is defined at creation time, with an upper limit of 5 GB.

Scheduled messages do not materialize in the queue until the defined enqueue time. For more details you could refer to [Messaging quotas](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-quotas#messaging-quotas).